# change UICollectionView cell imageview according to the indexpath.row selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

i have a collectionView which shows 5 cells. Now what i want to accompish is for example if i have tap on the first cell the imageView for the next cell is imageOne and if i tap on second cell the imageView will be imageTwo. in the detailViewController.

i am trying to accomplish this. here is what i've done so far
in prepareFor Segue in the UIView Controller with a UiCollectionView on it

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MainPush"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%li", indexPath.row);

// Getting the collectionView cell in the destination class
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
       DetailCollectionViewCell *cell = [[DetailCollectionView alloc] init];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Thailand"];
        }

    }
}
```

I i tap on this cell it goes to another collectionView exact like this but i want the images in the selected collectionView to be different according to the indexpath.row selected.

I do this but nothing happened

Comment: are you trying to pass an image to the detail view controller? In another word, are you trying to go to another view controller when a cell is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you are trying to pass an UIimage to the detailed view controller. Here are my suggestions. First, implement this:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CurrentImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //assume what you have an image object and you have an array contains images. 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MainPush" sender:nil];
}
```

This method is called when a cell is clicked. Inside, the **code assumes what you have an image object in your mainViewController and you have an array containing images.** Right below that, the performSegue method is called. **remember to set the SegueWay in your storyboard with your ID**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MainPush"]) {
        DetailedController *controller = (DetailedController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.image = CurrentImage;
    }
}
```

This is an important part. I assume that your viewController's name is DetailedController. 
1. You have to create an image object in your destination controller. 2. When the cell is clicked, it will set the currentImage object to the image that the user just clicked and pass it to the DetailViewController.

In the DetailController ViewDidLoad method, you can set the UIimageView.image to image.